# How can I make the user change any image on my wp theme just from the theme editor?

Tags: wordpress

How can I make the user change any image on my wp theme just from the theme editor?

**For example**: I have a background image on my theme footer that i hard-coded, I want to give the user(admin) the ability to change it from the theme editor, and thanks on advanced

I don't want to use something like this:

```
<div class="footer-background background-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_theme_file_uri( 'assets/images/bg.jpg' ) ?>)" >
```

If you can just give me a wp codex on this, it would be more than helpful, because I couldn't find any thing related to my problem on Google.

Comment: You will learn every thing here : https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/customizer-objects/

Comment: @Bazaim i couldn't find any thing related to my problem

Comment: You want to add some input file into the admin page "/wp-admin/customize.php" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you could do something like that (in functions.php) :

```
add_action( 'customize_register', function( $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->add_section(
        'section_img',
        array(
            'title' => 'Images',
            'priority' => 35,
        )
    );
    $wp_customize->add_setting(
        'footer_image'
    );
    $wp_customize->add_control(
        new WP_Customize_Image_Control(
            $wp_customize,
            'footer_image',
            array(
                'label' => 'Footer image',
                'section' => 'section_img',
                'settings' => 'footer_image'
            )
        )
    );
});
```

And you get the value by doing (in footer.php) :

```
get_theme_mod('footer_image');
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I do followings

1. Install ACF plugin
2. Create an option Page
3. Create new custom field (image field) and assign it to previously created options page.
4. Update footer template to show the image from back end like this
5. Update footer image src to get back end ACF field value.

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/